# No input file specified -LAMP(Apache)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Anyone can help with my htaccess file, its working with the root domain directory folder only, if i put the index file into the root domain directory and access page like this https://example.com/edr/login , it works nicely . However when i create folder  inside it and try to access site like this , https://example.com/createdfolder/edr/login, it says 'No input file exist. Below is my htaaccess file codes.  My $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] is set to 'login'

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is your front-controller expecting `createdfolder/` to be passed in the query string? Can you tolerate a slash prefix? eg. `/createdfolder/edr/login`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If to copy WordPress' .htaccess it would look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /createfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /createfolder/index.php [L]
```

Of course you can replace `createfolder/` with `your/path/`

Comment: alright let me try this, do you this if i dont bring the question mark  dollar sign in front of index.php it work?

Comment: If the `.htaccess` file still resides in the root then the first rule should read: `RewriteRule ^createfolder/index\.php$ - [L]` (although this rule is only an _optimisation_, it doesn't stop it from working.)

Comment: No its not, i have placed that in the edr folder, @MrWhite

Comment: @EleanorGotell In that case, the rules can be simplified further, since the `RewriteBase` directive is not required (it's not being used anyway in this particular case) and the `/createfolder/` prefix on the second rule's _substitution_ string can be removed. However, this is not doing the same thing that your rules are doing.

Comment: @EleanorGotell To confirm, your `.htaccess` file is now 2 subfolders deep, at `/createdfolder/edr/.htaccess`, whereas previously it was in the document root?

Comment: @MrWhite , yes sir, and -IT goldman-  answer worked but not previously when i dont hv to put ? there, now i have to do it like this /createdfolder/edr/?login before it works, initially it works like this /createdfolder/edr/login    , no question mark before 'login'

Comment: @IT goldman , pls anyway i can remove the question mark

Comment: You can try I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you all, i fixed it , now working, i modify this  a little RewriteRule . /createfolder/index.php [L]